# Logging into Google account using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, gmail, bots

I know this kind of questions have been asked but I couldn't find solution anyway. I'm trying to log in my Gmail using selenium so I need to log in my Google account firstly but when I enter my Gmail, google says that I couldn't be logged into the system because browser or app may not be protected. I tried to bypass this by logging into google via stackoverflow but it didn't help. Is there any way to solve this issue?
here's my code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time
from datetime import datetime



PATH = r"C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
```

Comment: it's in javascript which I absolutely don't know but I'll go with it somehow if nothing else shows up.

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/gmail-login-using-python-selenium/ Does this answer your question?

Comment: no, the same error shows up

Comment: I kind of solved this by using yahoo instead of Gmail. I disabled the webdriver flag, replaced cdc_ variables but nothing helped, I still couldn't sign in Gmail. Google somehow knows I am using selenium, however I could sign in   yahoo account without any issues